# store object for shopping cart in localstorage MERN

Tags: node.js, local-storage, shopping-cart, mern

I am stuck with the following problem:
I'm building a marketplace where buyers can buy from multiple sellers at the same time. I want the buyer to see all the items he/she is buying (no matter who's the seller) in the same cart, but internally, I need to store the items by seller. I was thinking about an object where the key is each seller's id, but I'm not finding how to store this in the localstorage.

My current code:

```
 cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
      : [],
 }
```

And this is how I add an item to the cart

```
 localStorage.setItem(
      'cartItems',
      JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)
 );
```

I'll be really really grateful if someone could help me out! Thank you in advance!!!